# Nested query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, union

Hello then the query below performs a select on a sql server database, the problem is that the total field is calculated as the total of all the tables, not of each , how can I run the account individually?Each table has a construction field and I want to calculate the  **Totale** field based on that field

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT Cantiere.IdCantiere,
              Cliente.RagioneSociale,
              'Preventivo' AS Tipo,
              Cantiere.NomeCantiere,
              Cantiere.StatoCantiere,
              (SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Prezzo * Quantita), 0)FROM ArticoloCantiere ) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM((Kilometri.Kilometri * CostoKilometrico) + DirittoChiamata), 0)
                                                                                           FROM Kilometri ) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CostoNoleggio + Trasporto), 0)FROM Noleggio) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Utente.CostoInterno * ((REPLACE((LEFT(CAST(REPLACE((CONVERT(varchar(5), CAST(CONVERT(varchar(5), (RisorseUmane.OreFine - RisorseUmane.OreInizio), 108) AS datetime) - CAST(REPLACE(RisorseUmane.Pausa, '.', ':') AS datetime), 108)), ':', ',') AS money) / 100, 2)), '.', '')) + (((CAST('0,' + (RIGHT(CAST(REPLACE((CONVERT(varchar(5), CAST(CONVERT(varchar(5), (RisorseUmane.OreFine - RisorseUmane.OreInizio), 108) AS datetime) - CAST(REPLACE(RisorseUmane.Pausa, '.', ':') AS datetime), 108)), ':', ',') AS money) / 100, 2)) AS money) / 100) * 100) / 60))), 0)
                                                                                                                                                                                  FROM RisorseUmane
                                                                                                                                                                                       INNER JOIN Utente ON RisorseUmane.IdUtente = Utente.IdUtente where IdCantiere=@IdCantiere) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Costo), 0)FROM SpeseSostenute where IdCantiere=@IdCantiere) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Costo), 0)FROM Ristorante )) AS Totale
       FROM Cantiere
            INNER JOIN Cliente ON Cantiere.IdCliente = Cliente.IdCliente
            INNER JOIN CantierePreventivo ON CantierePreventivo.IdCantierePreventivo = Cantiere.IdCantiere)
      UNION
      (SELECT Cantiere.IdCantiere,
              Cliente.RagioneSociale,
              'Consuntivo' AS Tipo,
              Cantiere.NomeCantiere,
              Cantiere.StatoCantiere,
              (SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Prezzo * Quantita), 0)FROM ArticoloCantiere ) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM((Kilometri.Kilometri * CostoKilometrico ) + DirittoChiamata), 0)
                                                                                           FROM Kilometri ) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CostoNoleggio + Trasporto), 0)FROM Noleggio ) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Utente.CostoInterno * ((REPLACE((LEFT(CAST(REPLACE((CONVERT(varchar(5), CAST(CONVERT(varchar(5), (RisorseUmane.OreFine - RisorseUmane.OreInizio), 108) AS datetime) - CAST(REPLACE(RisorseUmane.Pausa, '.', ':') AS datetime), 108)), ':', ',') AS money) / 100, 2)), '.', '')) + (((CAST('0,' + (RIGHT(CAST(REPLACE((CONVERT(varchar(5), CAST(CONVERT(varchar(5), (RisorseUmane.OreFine - RisorseUmane.OreInizio), 108) AS datetime) - CAST(REPLACE(RisorseUmane.Pausa, '.', ':') AS datetime), 108)), ':', ',') AS money) / 100, 2)) AS money) / 100) * 100) / 60))), 0)
                                                                                                                                                                                  FROM RisorseUmane
                                                                                                                                                                                       INNER JOIN Utente ON RisorseUmane.IdUtente = Utente.IdUtente ) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Costo), 0)FROM SpeseSostenute ) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Costo), 0)FROM Ristorante )) AS Totale
       FROM Cantiere
            INNER JOIN Cliente ON Cantiere.IdCliente = Cliente.IdCliente
            INNER JOIN CantiereConsuntivo ON CantiereConsuntivo.IdCantiereConsuntivo = Cantiere.IdCantiere)) q
ORDER BY q.Totale DESC;
```

[image: Image of error -]

Comment: Consumable sample data, and expected results will greatly help us, help you.

Comment: Please update your question and copy/paste the error text/message, Errors in images are not allowed in Stackoverflow : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

your totale column in all of tables is same. you must calculate total in each section by joining total result of those section with associated Cantiere  row. for more help please give your tables structure and sample data.